# Why is "bicycle" pronounced differently from other obviously related words?

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling

The word *bicycle* is pronounced /'baɪsɪkəl/ (bahy-si-kuhl), like *sickle*. However, the words *unicycle* and *motorcycle* both have the *-cycle* pronounced as /-'saɪkəl/ (sahy-kuhl). Is there some sort of reason for this, or is this just a vagary of English pronunciation?

Comment: Likely because words having two long i's together are deemed harder to pronounce, and as such, its pronunciation tends to change.

Comment: Probably people just naturally avoiding the same sound twice; ie. "cy" rhymed with "bi"

Comment: And also *tricycle*...

Comment: It's also worth noting that some accents (particularly in England) do have *motorcycle* with [-sɪkl].

Comment: @Jon Purdy: Would that be mot *or* sick le or *mo* tor sick le? I can't find that pronunciation in a dictionary.

Comment: @minitech: The stress is on the first syllable only. It's uncommon, and kinda formal-sounding, but I have heard it.

Comment: @Jon Purdy Some southern US regions call it a motor-sickle as well. I always wondered about this myself.

Comment: @gms8994: Very true. I've got no more clue than you have, though it may be interesting to note some Southern accents are non-rhotic, implying a closer relationship with the *-sickle* accent(s) across the pond. On a side note, shot in the dark says you're an RIT alum.

Comment: As Arlo Guthrie sings: ["I don't want a pickle... I just wanna ride my motorsickle.  I don't wanna tickle... I'd rather ride my motorsickle.  And I don't wanna die - I just wanna ride on my motorcy... cle."](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g266Uwp6ZnI)

Comment: I've never heard bahy-si-kuhl, only bye-si-kul/bye-sik-ul

Comment: "Is there some sort of reason for this" -- obviously, in each case the first syllable is stressed and the second isn't. MOtorCYcle, UNiCYcle, BIcyCLE, TRIcyCLE.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/603199/2085).

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Although such variation could be the result of things like when the word was borrowed into the language, this variation is probably due to the prosodic structure of the words; we get different vowel sounds because of the way that stress influences vowel quality in English.

In English, unstressed vowels are generally reduced.  Take the word *record* for example.

- The **noun** form takes first syllable stress: [ˈrɛ kɚd]. If you aren't familiar with [IPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet), note in particular the [ɛ] vowel and the [ɚ] r-colored schwa vowel.  Schwa (and sometimes [ɪ]) is what often shows up in reduced, unstressed vowels in English.  Since stress is on the first syllable, we get the r-colored schwa in the second syllable.
- The **verb** form takes second syllable stress: [rə ˈkoɹd].  Note that the now-unstressed [ɛ] was reduced to [ə], schwa, while the [ɚ] now retains the full [o] sound (with an [ɹ] "r" after it).

Now for *bicycle* and *unicycle*:

- *bicycle* [ˈbaɪ sɪ kəl] has primary stress on the **first syllable**.  The "cy" syllable is unstressed, and so it is pronounced as a mere [sɪ] (or even [sə] by some).  Note that *tricycle* has the same stress pattern, and has the same vowel.
- *unicycle* [ˈju nɪ ˌsaɪ kəl], being a longer word, has multiple stressed syllables.  Primary stress, again, falls on syllable #1, but the important thing is that **secondary stress falls on syllable #3, the "cy" syllable**.  This means that "cy" is pronounced as a full [saɪ] instead of a reduced [sɪ].  Note that *motorcycle* has the same stress pattern and, again, same vowel.

Comment: D'oh! You beat me by a few minutes.

Comment: Also note *tricycle* follows the pattern.

Comment: Worth noting that the IPA for the "record" example is fairly specific to US English (eg in BrE it's usually ['rɛ kɔ:d] vs [rɪ 'kɔ:d] - no schwas in sight :) - but the same principle does apply in general, and plenty of other examples *do* reduce fully into a schwa even in BrE.

Comment: Nice answer! I also observed that vowels in English are usually shifted when a syllable is reduced to an unstressed one. +1 to 100!

Answer (score 64):

The reason boils down to English prosody and stress patterns.

First, a general observation that the vowel [aɪ], which is the first vowel in *cycle*, very rarely occurs in unstressed syllables. Unstressed syllables that would otherwise contain this vowel tend to reduce it to [ɪ] or even [ə], as nearly all English vowels are so reduced when they occur in unstressed syllables. From this we can infer a general pattern that the vowel in *cycle* will only be pronounced as [aɪ] as long as the vowel is stressed.

The second observation is that both *motorcycle* and *unicycle* consist of a pair of trochees: MO-tor-CY-cle, U-ni-CY-cle. The primary stress in both words falls on the first syllable, but the secondary stress falls on the first syllable of *-cycle*. In this context the vowel retains its full pronunciation.

*Bicycle*, however, has only one syllable before the *-cycle*, and the primary stress falls on this syllable. English does not allow two stressed syllables in a row in native words, which means that the second syllable of *bicycle* has no secondary stress. In turn, this means that the vowel [aɪ] is reduced to just [ɪ] in this context.

There are a few exceptions to this rule about two stressed syllables in a row, but they are all compounds or neologisms: *fly-by, cry-baby*. And in fact, the oldest spelling of the word *bicycle* is *bi-cycle*, where the hyphen is meant to indicate that the word is a compound and suggests the pronunciation b[aɪ]-c[aɪ]cle. But as the word *bicycle* became more common, the word was adapted to the native stress pattern, requiring reduction of the vowel in the second syllable.

Comment: I accepted another answer as *the* answer but upvoted you for the great examples of exceptions at the end.